# Remove Mandatory ActiveSync Passcode

Tags: iphone, passwords, jailbreak, activesync

The exchange server I connect to with my iPhone requires me to put a pass code on the phone.  Is there a third party app (or some other means) that will allow me to remove it and leave the mail account active?

Yes, I realize it's there for a purpose; it's just an annoyance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

ActiveSync is a protocol that mail app makers have to license from Microsoft, and they're not likely to stay licensed long if they lie to the exchange server about their provisioning status!

The only way to remove the requirement is to have your friendly neighbourhood Exchange Admin alter your account's ActiveSync policy.